# Plugins for creating and styling custom Editor Windows like C#/C++ Form Designer or “Web Inspector”?

Tags: unity-game-engine, utilities

`Unity3d` allows to construct window with custom UI. Just need to use `EditorGUI/EditorGUILayout` classes and their static methods.
Example of custom window:

[image]

The problem is that all the components have to be added manually via script. Then need to save, switch to Editor, wait for little compile things, and then we can see the result.

In web-development people use `Web Inspector` (for example, we can press <kbd>F12</kbd> in `chrome`, Tab `Elements` -> `Styles`). We can add all needed properties to element and can see the result in real-time.

[image]

**EDIT.** another example (better than previous): we know `C# winFormApp`, `C++ MFC` e.t.c, which has form designer. We can choose any elements and set their properties:

[image]

It would be nice to have similar plugins for Unity

So. Does `Unity3d` have similar tools, utilities, plugins? Utilities to inspect code and editing styles (position, margin, padding, background, width, height, color  e.t.c.)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found something interesting...[Editor window designer](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/editor-extension-editor-window-designer.337474/)

The plugin is almost what I need

The project had been started but not completed yet.
As [the author says](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rel-open-source-editor-window-designer.375900/): he decided to release Editor Window Designer as an open source project, that code [is here](https://github.com/ahrenm/uAssist)

For now plugin allows add elements and styling them (position, padding, width, height, e.t.c)
Base demo window:

[image: img1]

And here is hierarchy window and properties of concrete element

[image: img2]

I wonder why Unity developers (or someone else) still didn't do something like that?  It is very useful and necessary thing...